# WebGL: работа с переменными JS

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, шейдеры

Есть такой код HTML:

```
<script>
var some = 1;
</script>


<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="notjs">


  void main() {

  }
</script>



<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="notjs">

  void main() {  
  }
</script>
```

Могу ли я получить доступ к переменной JS some в фрагментом или вершинном шейдере? Если да, то каким способом?

Answer (score 1):

в шейдерах можете только получить его значение, передав при помощи `webGL API` через `uniform`.

вобщем, в js коде нужно вот это

`glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "some"), some);`

а в шейдерах (передавать можно как во фрагментный так и вершинный) определить его как `uniform`

```
precision highp float;
uniform int some;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = //...
}
```

а что такое `program` надеюсь пояснять не надо ?